# searching a listview uwp

Tags: listview, search, uwp

I have a a searchButton and searchTextBox and want to use them to search a listview,  What I would like is for the listview to change its selection to the row that has the value in the first column and then I would just scrollview to selection.  My problem is accessing the elements within the listview and comparing them to the string in the searchtext box, here is what I have as a listview

```
  <ListView x:Name="ctlist" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="400" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1000" Background="AntiqueWhite">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=ctlList, Path=ActualWidth }" Padding="0" Margin="0" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="adminID" Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="adminPASS" Width="100" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="adName" Text="{Binding Path=adminName}" Grid.Column="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= adminPass}" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </Grid>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

How would I cycle through the listview and compare the searchbox text to the row/column value?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "What I would like is for the listview to change its selection to the row that has the value in the first column and then I would just scrollview to selection"?

Comment: Yes, so if I were to display the data, as in a list of admin names and admin passwords, if it goes beyond the listview capacity it will use a scroll bar, so If i scroll down to the bottom and select an item and scroll back to the top, when I do                 ctlist.ScrollIntoView(ctlist.SelectedItem);
it will scroll me to the selected item, so i would like the list selection to be changed on a search to where the adminName would be = searchtextbox, or if there was a way to directly access the items when I select something within the listview

Comment: So, if i were to do a search it would select the item and then I could scrollview to the selection, then my main problem is how would I access the data in the row/column of the selection so that I could use other buttons/functions like edit/remove to manipulate the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I cycle through the listview and compare the searchbox text to the row/column value?

You don't need to consider about searching the `ListView` control itself. Actually the data showed in the `ListView` is binding from data collection in your code snippet. You can just compare the search box text with the items you bind to the `Listview` and set the march item as selected in `ListView`.

> then I would just scrollview to selection

For this, just try to use [ScrollIntoView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br242911) method.
And a completed code example like follows:

```
public sealed partial class ListViewSearch : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<admin> admins = new ObservableCollection<admin> { };
    public ListViewSearch()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        for(int i=1;i<30;i++)
        {
            admin item = new admin { adminName = "ID" + i, adminPass = "password" + i };
            admins.Add(item);
        }         
        ctlist.ItemsSource = admins;
    }

    private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string searchtext = txtserch.Text;
        foreach(admin adminitem in admins)
        {
            if(adminitem.adminName.Contains(searchtext))
            {
                ctlist.SelectedItem = adminitem;
                ctlist.ScrollIntoView(ctlist.SelectedItem);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
public class admin
{
    public string adminName { get; set; }
    public string adminPass { get; set; }
}
```

More details about `ListView` please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlListView).